# how to search for the ip addresses in cidr notation

Tags: java, mysql, network-programming, ip-address, cidr

I need to search for the entries in the mysql database with following ipaddress “192.168.0.1/20 ”

Note: ip addresses stored are varchars (ex. 192.168.0.3,192.168.0.4)

```
Address:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.0000 0000.00000001
Netmask:   255.255.240.0 = 20   11111111.11111111.1111 0000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.15.255           00000000.00000000.0000 1111.11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/20       11000000.10101000.0000 0000.00000000
HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.0000 0000.00000001
HostMax:   192.168.15.254       11000000.10101000.0000 1111.11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.15.255       11000000.10101000.0000 1111.11111111
Hosts/Net: 4094                  Class C, Private Internet
```

my solution is to find to the network address from given cidr notation (replace 0 with "*") and search for **192.168.*.*** entries in database as they are stored in strings. It works but I am  not sure whether this is correct

can any point out the problem or more optimal solution than this?

Comment: your solution with 192.168.*.* wil not work, because 192.168.0.1/20 has max host addr 192.168.15.254, but you could have addresses in your database like 192.168.16.1, 192.168.16.2, etc.

Comment: aha thanks stanislav (face palm movement)

Comment: as for me, I see only 2 solutions at the moment: to get all addresses and use IN clause, or take a min and max hosts, split them into 4 groups, make for every group a regexp if they are not the same, then split 4 regexp groups together with dots and trying to call the query with regexp. but it could lead to not optimal select...

Comment: how about this "SELECT * from  addresses   where INET_ATON(`ip_address`) > {STARTING_IP_ADDRESS} && INET_ATON(`ip_address`) < {EDING_IP_ADDRESS}; (https://www.ultratools.com/tools/netMaskResult?ipAddress=192.168.0.1%2F20+)

Comment: Seems to be good, I'm not very familiar to MySQL, mostly to Oracle or PG and didn't know that MySQL has such a function. But don't you need to make  INET_ATON({STARTING_IP_ADDRESS}) too and make it also equals?

Comment: yup you are right forgot to add them , will wait for other responses as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91886/discussion-between-rockyit86-and-stanislav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following works if you have single IP address per VARCHAR field.*

Correct way to match IP addresses against their network using netmask is through [`INET_ATON()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)/[`INET_NTOA()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

There are several steps, though. First use the following to convert your length to subnetmask:

```
SET @l=20;
SELECT INET_NTOA(0xffffffff >> (32-@l) << (32-@l));
```

That's just to convey the idea, to make this useful you could do the following:

```
SELECT 0xffffffff >> (32-@l) << (32-@l) INTO @mask;
```

For the actual matching of the address against your network address you can use `INET_` functions with bitwise operators, for example:

```
SET @l=20;
SET @nw='192.168.0.0';
SELECT 0xffffffff >> (32-@l) << (32-@l) INTO @mask;
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
 WHERE (INET_ATON(addrfield) & @mask) = INET_ATON(@nw);
```

Of course you may roll this into a single statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
     WHERE (INET_ATON(addrfield) & (0xffffffff >> (32-@l) << (32-@l))) = INET_ATON('192.168.0.0');
```

Comment: can you check my last comment "SELECT * from addresses where INET_ATON(ip_address) > {STARTING_IP_ADDRESS} && INET_ATON(ip_address) < {EDING_IP_ADDRESS}" will this not be sufficient ?

Comment: @rockyit86, yes, that works if you have first and last address, i.e. network and broadcast addresses for the said subnet.

Comment: Interesting use of `LPAD()` and `RPAD()` to build a mask @vhu.  Alternatives for generating the mask would include `0xffffffff >> @l << @l` or `~0 >> 32 & ~0 << @l`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, agreed that's much better way.

Comment: It would have been if I had done the subtraction, d'oh. `(32 - @l)` indeed.  +1